# ProGuard can cause incorrect calculations

Tags: java, android, proguard, android-sdk-tools

I have met a pretty strange bug. The following small piece of code uses a rather simple math.

```
protected double C_n_k(int n, int k)
{
  if(k<0 || k>n)
    return 0;
  double s=1;
  for(int i=1;i<=k;i++)
    s=s*(n+1-i)/i;
  return s;
}
```

**Edit** Using ProGuard can make it go wrong on some devices. I have it confirmed on HTC One S Android 4.1.1 build 3.16.401.8, but judging by e-mails I got, a lot of phones with Android 4+ are affected. For some of them (Galaxy S3), american operator-branded phones are affected, while international versions are not. Many phones are not affected.

Below is the code of activity which calculates C(n,k) for 1<=n<25 and 0<=k<=n. On device mentioned above the first session gives correct results, but the subsequent launches show incorrect results, each time in different positions.

I have 3 questions:

1. How can it be? Even if ProGuard made something wrong, calculations should be consistent between devices and sessions.
2. How can we avoid it? I know substituting `double` by `long` is fine in this case, but it is not a universal method. Dropping using `double` or releasing not-obfuscated versions is out of question.
3. What Android versions are affected? I was quite quick with fixing it in the game, so I just know that many players have seen it, and at least the most had Android 4.0

Overflow is out of question, because sometimes I see mistake in calculating `C(3,3)=3/1*2/2*1/3`. Usually incorrect numbers start somewhere in C(10,...), and look like a phone has "forgotten" to make some divisions.

My SDK tools are 22.3 (the latest), and I have seen it in builds created by both Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA.

Activity code:

```
package com.karmangames.mathtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MathTestActivity extends Activity
{
  /**
   * Called when the activity is first created.
   */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String s="";
    for(int n=0;n<=25;n++)
      for(int k=0;k<=n;k++)
      {
        double v=C_n_k_double(n,k);
        s+="C("+n+","+k+")="+v+(v==C_n_k_long(n,k) ? "" : "   Correct is "+C_n_k_long(n,k))+"\n";
        if(k==n)
          s+="\n";
      }
    System.out.println(s);
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(s);
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
  }

  protected double C_n_k_double(int n, int k)
  {
    if(k<0 || k>n)
      return 0;
    //C_n^k
    double s=1;
    for(int i=1;i<=k;i++)
      s=s*(n+1-i)/i;
    return s;
  }

  protected double C_n_k_long(int n, int k)
  {
    if(k<0 || k>n)
      return 0;
    //C_n^k
    long s=1;
    for(int i=1;i<=k;i++)
      s=s*(n+1-i)/i;
    return (double)s;
  }

}
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  >

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Example of wrong calculation results (remember, it's different every time I try it)

```
C(0,0)=1.0

C(1,0)=1.0
C(1,1)=1.0

C(2,0)=1.0
C(2,1)=2.0
C(2,2)=1.0

C(3,0)=1.0
C(3,1)=3.0
C(3,2)=3.0
C(3,3)=1.0

C(4,0)=1.0
C(4,1)=4.0
C(4,2)=6.0
C(4,3)=4.0
C(4,4)=1.0

C(5,0)=1.0
C(5,1)=5.0
C(5,2)=10.0
C(5,3)=10.0
C(5,4)=30.0   Correct is 5.0
C(5,5)=1.0

C(6,0)=1.0
C(6,1)=6.0
C(6,2)=15.0
C(6,3)=40.0   Correct is 20.0
C(6,4)=90.0   Correct is 15.0
C(6,5)=144.0   Correct is 6.0
C(6,6)=120.0   Correct is 1.0

C(7,0)=1.0
C(7,1)=7.0
C(7,2)=21.0
C(7,3)=35.0
C(7,4)=105.0   Correct is 35.0
C(7,5)=504.0   Correct is 21.0
C(7,6)=840.0   Correct is 7.0
C(7,7)=720.0   Correct is 1.0

C(8,0)=1.0
C(8,1)=8.0
C(8,2)=28.0
C(8,3)=112.0   Correct is 56.0
C(8,4)=70.0
C(8,5)=1344.0   Correct is 56.0
C(8,6)=3360.0   Correct is 28.0
C(8,7)=5760.0   Correct is 8.0
C(8,8)=5040.0   Correct is 1.0

C(9,0)=1.0
C(9,1)=9.0
C(9,2)=36.0
C(9,3)=168.0   Correct is 84.0
C(9,4)=756.0   Correct is 126.0
C(9,5)=3024.0   Correct is 126.0
C(9,6)=10080.0   Correct is 84.0
C(9,7)=25920.0   Correct is 36.0
C(9,8)=45360.0   Correct is 9.0
C(9,9)=40320.0   Correct is 1.0

C(10,0)=1.0
C(10,1)=10.0
C(10,2)=45.0
C(10,3)=120.0
C(10,4)=210.0
C(10,5)=252.0
C(10,6)=25200.0   Correct is 210.0
C(10,7)=120.0
C(10,8)=315.0   Correct is 45.0
C(10,9)=16800.0   Correct is 10.0
C(10,10)=1.0
```

Comment: Sounds very unlikely. Have you tried logging each value of `s` in that loop to figure out how the calculation differs?

Comment: Which is "correct?" if either?

Comment: FWIW, in math, C(12, 4) = 495.

Comment: The problem will be with your code for sure.  One word - debugger!

Comment: Since `long` works where `double` doesn't, and you claim there is no overflow, I would suggest trying to use the `strictfp` keyword *if* the differences were much smaller. With such a large difference, (and the fact that no precision is being lost in this example) I highly doubt it is a rounding error, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android team member has posted a possible solution in a comment to my [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63790). If I add `android:vmSafeMode="true"` to `application` element of manifest-file, all calculations are performed correctly. This option is not well documented and honestly I do not know how much will it affect the speed, but at least the math will be correct. I will mark it as correct answer until a better one is found.

Answer (score 2):

The original code and the processed code work fine on the Java VM and on most Dalvik VMs, so it must be valid. If the processed code produces spurious results on a few Dalvik VMs, chances are that the problem is caused by the JIT compiler in those VMs. Google's Android team should then look into it.

The most obvious optimization that ProGuard applies here is inlining the method. A few branch instructions and local variables are reordered in the final bytecode, but the execution flow of this small piece of code is fundamentally the same. It's difficult to determine how ProGuard could avoid the problem. You could disable the optimization step entirely.

You could check if inlining the code manually causes the same problems, without ProGuard (the problem doesn't seem to occur on my devices).

(I am the developer of ProGuard)

Comment: Thank you Eric! I was going to post an issue to android team, just wanted to wait for a day in case I've missed something obvious and somebody points it out. I'm using ProGuard for mobile development for about 10 years, and you make a great work. Keep it up!

Comment: Eric, I've checked a few options: `-dontoptimize` does not help, `-dontobfuscate` helps, but who wants unobfuscated code in commercial projects? I don't think a method was inlined, because I see all 3 methods in `mapping.txt`. Unfortunately I swapped to MacOS some time ago, and miss some tools I've used for reverse engineering. I've posted an issue 63790 for android, and hope to get some answer, but I don't think it will be soon.

Comment: The obfuscation step only renames the methods to 'a' and 'b' and removes debug information about local variables, but it indeed causes the `dx` compiler to emit different bytecode. You can try if `-keepattributes LocalVariableTable` makes the difference. You can use `dexdump` from the Android SDK to see the bytecode of the application.

Comment: Yes, `-keepattributes LocalVariableTable` helps, at least on my phone. Which one is less risky, `vmSafeMode` or this?

Comment: You should keep the attribute then; it's also useful for interpreting obfuscated stack traces (see the ProGuard documentation). Disabling JIT compilation with the `vmSafeMode` flag probably is not advisable, since it affects performance very badly. Now, if the attribute makes the difference, you can probably also get the problem without ProGuard, by compiling with the flag `-g:none`.

Comment: I have not noticed any impact of switched on `vmSafeMode` in my games and I have also found [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/VKZLSdilt08). It does not tell what exactly was wrong, but since I have only 1 phone out of many affected, I thought that switching on `vmSafeMode` is a safer way.

Answer (score 1):

This all turns out to be a JIT compiler bug which the ProGuard optimizations just happened to trigger.

As the AOSP [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63790) explains:

> There was a window in the Jelly Bean release time in which the JIT would mistakenly optimize away uses of floating point double constants which were identical in the low 32 bits (and also had a few other conditions met).  The defect was introduced in late November of 2012 in the internal Google tree, and in February of 2013 in aosp.  Fixed in April of 2013.

More detailed explanation in this other [AOSP issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65750).