# Double precision value computation errors on MediaTek processors

Tags: android, floating-point, double, jit

I've found that one of my application posted on the market produces weird results on some phones. Upon investigation it turns out there is an issue with one function which computes distance between two GeoPoints - sometimes it returns completely wrong value. This issue reproduces only on devices with [MediaTek MT6589](http://www.mediatek.com/_en/promotion/MT6589_overview.php) SoC (aka MTK6589). And AFAIK all of such devices have Android 4.2 installed.

**Update** I was also able to reproduce the bug on Lenovo S6000 tablet with [MediaTek MT8125/8389](http://www.mediatek.com/_en/01_products/04_pro.php?sn=1085) chip and on [Fly IQ444 Quattro](http://www.fly-phone.com/devices/smartphones/iq444quattrodiamond2/) with MT6589 and with Android **4.1** installed.

I created a test project which helps to reproduce the bug. It runs computation repeatedly for 1'000 or 100'000 iterations. To exclude possibility of threading issues computation is performed on the UI thread (with small pauses to keep UI responding). In the test project I used just a part from the original distance formula:

```
private double calcX() {
    double t = 1.0;
    double X = 0.5 + t / 16384;
    return X;
}
```

As you can check by yourself on [web2.0calc.com](http://web2.0calc.com/?q=t%20%3D%201%3B%20A%20%3D%200.5%20%2B%20t%20%2F%2016384) the value of `X` should be approximately: `0.50006103515625`.
However on the devices with MT6589 chip often the wrong value is computed: `2.0`.

Project is [available at Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/test-mtk-double-bug/) ([APK](https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0ByH_RlhVvDGBV0FTSnNuS2xvNlE) is available also). The source of the test class is presented below:

```
public class MtkTestActivity extends Activity {

  static final double A = 0.5;
  static final double B = 1;
  static final double D = 16384;

  static final double COMPUTED_CONST = A + B / D;

  /*
   * Main calculation where bug occurs
   */
  public double calcX() {
    double t = B;
    double X = A + t / D;
    return X;
  }

  class TestRunnable implements Runnable {

    static final double EP = 0.00000000001;

    static final double EXPECTED_LOW = COMPUTED_CONST - EP;

    static final double EXPECTED_HIGH = COMPUTED_CONST + EP;

    public void run() {
      for (int i = 0; i < SMALL_ITERATION; i++) {
        double A = calcX();

        if (A < EXPECTED_LOW || A > EXPECTED_HIGH) {
          mFailedInCycle = true;
          mFails++;
          mEdit.getText().append("FAILED on " + mIteration + " iteration with: " + A + '\n');
        }
        mIteration++;
      }

      if (mIteration % 5000 == 0) {
        if (mFailedInCycle) {
          mFailedInCycle = false;
        } else {
          mEdit.getText().append("passed " + mIteration + " iterations\n");
        }
      }

      if (mIteration < mIterationsCount) {
        mHandler.postDelayed(new TestRunnable(), DELAY);
      } else {
        mEdit.getText().append("\nFinished test with " + mFails + " fails");
      }
    }

  }

  public void onTestClick(View v) {
    startTest(IT_10K);
  }

  public void onTestClick100(View v) {
    startTest(IT_100K);
  }

  private void startTest(int iterationsCount) {
    Editable text = mEdit.getText();
    text.clear();
    text.append("\nStarting " + iterationsCount + " iterations test...");
    text.append("\n\nExpected result " + COMPUTED_CONST + "\n\n");
    mIteration = 0;
    mFails = 0;
    mFailedInCycle = false;
    mIterationsCount = iterationsCount;
    mHandler.postDelayed(new TestRunnable(), 100);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
    mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtText1);
  }

  private static final int IT_10K = 1000;

  private static final int IT_100K = 100000;

  private static final int SMALL_ITERATION = 50;

  private static final int DELAY = 10;

  private int mIteration;

  private int mFails;

  private boolean mFailedInCycle;

  private Handler mHandler;

  private int mIterationsCount;

  private EditText mEdit;

}
```

To fix the issue it's enough to just change all `double` to `float` in `calcX()` method.

**Further investigation**
Turning off JIT (by adding `android:vmSafeMode="true"` to the app manifest) fixes bug as well.

Have anyone seen this bug before? Maybe this is a known issue?

p.s.: if anyone would be able to reproduce this bug on the device with other chip, or could test it with any MediaTek chip and Android >= 4.3, I will highly appreciate it.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63790 details what looks like this exact problem on HTC One S devices running Android 4.1.1, as well as a number of other devices. In this bug, it initially looks like some bad interaction with ProGuard, but further analysis has reduced it to some smaller set of Dalvik bytecode. The root cause hasn't been determined yet, and the only workaround is the one you've discovered to turn off the JIT.

Comment: Yes, it seems very similar to what I posted. A link to Google code contains a test apk you can try, and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20573598/proguard-can-cause-incorrect-calculations) is a more detailed description and discussion with creator of ProGuard.

Comment: I am able to reproduce this bug in a MT6589 phone(Canvas HD) with Android 4.2.1.

Comment: @ScottBarta yes, they look similar, however I was unable to reproduce #63790 on the device with MT6589 (used APK provided by Dmitry). Also this one differs from #63790 in the way it happens periodically but not all the time. On the last few days I investigated the bug a little bit more, I'll present the results of that investigations in my answer soon.

Comment: Sorry, I was at the conference when I got your e-mail. I just tried your apk on the phone affected by mine. I tested 100K iterations quitting every time or several times without quitting and have not seen anything different from "0 fails" after about 20 tests. So, these issues seem to be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a JIT bug that was active in the JellyBean source from late 2012 through early 2013.  In short, if two or more double-precision constants that were different in the high 32 bits, but identical in the low 32 bits were used in the same basic block the JIT would think they were the same, and inappropriately optimize one of them away.

I introduced the defect in: https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/47280/

and fixed it in: https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/57602/

The defect should not appear in any recent Android builds.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing could possibly be related to the processor hardware. 
There are some notorious examples in computing history:
1994, Some Intel Pentium processors did have an error, producing floating point calculation errors(FDIV bug). This was only as of the 4th digit after the decimal point. Intel ultimately put in place a replacement program to swap the defective CPUs for good ones. 
The DEC VAX 11/785 (introduced 1984) had a design flaw in its (optional)floating point coprocessor. Due to a race condition in hardware, sometimes the floating point coprocessor returned an arbitrary value instead of the desired result on some machines. Digital Equipment Corporation put in place a program to replace the (5 large printed circuit boards) coprocessor at all customers with a hardware maintenance contract in place.

I'd suggest that you could try to do some more testing on a wider hardware base to better understand the problem. If the problem would be really be related to hardware, I'm guessing your best approach would be to find a way to work around the problem & document it for other developers.

Answer (score 1):

> Have anyone seen this bug before? Maybe this is a known issue?

These show up on occasion on a couple of the Android mailing lists.

I believe what you are seeing is the effect of (1) different CPUs and their handling of floating point values, and (2) storage sizes differences that lead to different roundings and truncations.

For (1) use something like the following is used in native code:

- `_controlfp(_PC_24, _MCW_PC);`
- `_controlfp(_RC_NEAR, _MCW_RC);`

For (2) use the common storage size, which is a `float`.

There's sometimes another related problem in the native world: a float is passed to a function, but the value at the function is always `0.0f` (rather than the non-0 value used to invoke the function). You can clear that with `-mfloat-abi=softfp`. See [Hard-float and JNI](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-ndk/NbUq9FDDZOo/TJJsAS6nM7wJ).

Unfortunately, you are at the mercy of the manufacturer when using their port of Android Java. Enjoy their tweaks, oversights and implementation bugs. At least its not [corrupting your VM](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33032).

Answer (score 1):

I spent the last week investigating this issue and here's what I've found:

- This bug has been noticed before by the users of MT6589 devices (e.g. [here](https://code.google.com/p/open-gpstracker/issues/detail?id=400) and [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2431933))
- Common workaround was the disabling of JIT (for specific app or for the whole system)
- I was able to reproduce this issue on the couple of devices with MT6589 and MT8125/8389, <strike>currently it hasn't been reproduced on the devices with chips other than mentioned</strike> see update sections below
- The expression which reproduces the bug if far simpler than I posted in the question, just:
  `X = A + b / D`
- The delay between calculations is a crucial part of the bug: without it bug appears sporadically, with a small sleep after calculation it reproduces always (once the code has been JITed)
- I've created a script which assembles a simple jar file and runs `dalvikvm` directly, passing parameters to it. This allowed to set jit threshold and receive output ARM code generated by JIT
- Passing `-Xjitdisableopt:1` to the Dalvik fixes the issue (this parameter disables [kLoadStoreElimination](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/dalvik/vm/compiler/codegen/Optimizer.h#27) optimization). One may also add `dalvik.vm.extra-opts=-Xjitdisableopt:1` to `build.prop` file as a quick workaround which preserves JIT (root and reboot are required)
- Though this issue looks similar to the bug [#63790](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63790) mentioned by Scott Barta, I think it's the different one (also author of mentioned bug Dmitry have confirmed that this "Mediatek" bug doesn't reproduces on the phone affected by #63790)
- **UPDATE:** I've putted `libdvm.so` (from Fly IQ4410 with MT6589 chip) on the emulator and the bug reproduced there. But if I use `libdvm.so` compiled from the Android 4.2 sources the bug disappears. It looks like there is an issue with JIT compiled code produced by some specific version of `libdvm` library shipped with affected devices
- **UPDATE:** Successfully reproduced the bug on Samsung Ace 2 phone ([NovaThor U8500](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NovaThor#List_of_Nova_and_NovaThor_SoCs), Android 4.1.2) using the same technique as above - took `libdvm.so` from Fly IQ444 (MT6589, Android 4.1.2)

I've submitted a bug report [#65750](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65750).

Here are the source and the JIT assembly output of the test used to reproduce the bug:

```
public class Calc {

  static final double A = 0.5;
  static final double B = 1;
  static final double D = 16384;

  public double calcX() {
    double t = B;
    double X = A + t / D;
    return X;
  }    
}
```

JIT output for a usual run of Dalvik:

```
D/dalvikvm: Dumping LIR insns
D/dalvikvm: installed code is at 0x45deb000
D/dalvikvm: total size is 124 bytes
D/dalvikvm: 0x45deb000 (0000): data    0xc278(49784)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45deb002 (0002): data    0x457a(17786)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45deb004 (0004): data    0x0044(68)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45deb006 (0006): ldr     r0, [r15pc, -#8]
D/dalvikvm: 0x45deb00a (000a): ldr     r1, [r0, #0]
D/dalvikvm: 0x45deb00c (000c): adds    r1, r1, #1
D/dalvikvm: 0x45deb00e (000e): str     r1, [r0, #0]
D/dalvikvm: -------- entry offset: 0x0000
D/dalvikvm: L0x4579e28c:
D/dalvikvm: -------- dalvik offset: 0x0000 @ const-wide/high16 v0, (#16368), (#0)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45deb010 (0010): vldr    d8, [r15, #96]
D/dalvikvm: -------- dalvik offset: 0x0002 @ const-wide/high16 v2, (#16352), (#0)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45deb014 (0014): vmov.f64  d9, d8
D/dalvikvm: -------- dalvik offset: 0x0004 @ const-wide/high16 v4, (#16592), (#0)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45deb018 (0018): vmov.f64  d10, d9
D/dalvikvm: -------- dalvik offset: 0x0006 @ div-double/2addr v0, v4, (#0)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45deb01c (001c): vdivd   d8, d8, d10
D/dalvikvm: -------- dalvik offset: 0x0007 @ add-double/2addr v0, v2, (#0)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45deb020 (0020): vadd    d8, d8, d9
D/dalvikvm: -------- dalvik offset: 0x0008 @ return-wide v0, (#0), (#0)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45deb024 (0024): vmov.f64  d11, d8
D/dalvikvm: 0x45deb028 (0028): vstr    d11, [r6, #16]
D/dalvikvm: 0x45deb02c (002c): vstr    d8, [r5, #0]
D/dalvikvm: 0x45deb030 (0030): vstr    d10, [r5, #16]
D/dalvikvm: 0x45deb034 (0034): vstr    d9, [r5, #8]
D/dalvikvm: 0x45deb038 (0038): blx_1   0x45dea028
D/dalvikvm: 0x45deb03a (003a): blx_2   see above
D/dalvikvm: 0x45deb03c (003c): b       0x45deb040 (L0x4579f068)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45deb03e (003e): undefined
D/dalvikvm: L0x4579f068:
D/dalvikvm: -------- reconstruct dalvik PC : 0x457b83f4 @ +0x0008
D/dalvikvm: 0x45deb040 (0040): ldr     r0, [r15pc, #28]
D/dalvikvm: Exception_Handling:
D/dalvikvm: 0x45deb044 (0044): ldr     r1, [r6, #108]
D/dalvikvm: 0x45deb046 (0046): blx     r1
D/dalvikvm: -------- end of chaining cells (0x0048)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45deb060 (0060): .word (0x457b83f4)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45deb064 (0064): .word (0)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45deb068 (0068): .word (0x40d00000)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45deb06c (006c): .word (0)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45deb070 (0070): .word (0x3fe00000)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45deb074 (0074): .word (0)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45deb078 (0078): .word (0x3ff00000)
D/dalvikvm: End LCalc;calcX, 6 Dalvik instructions.
```

The most interesting part is:

```
vldr    d8, [r15, #96]   ;  d8 := 1.0
vmov.f64  d9, d8         ;  d9 := d8
vmov.f64  d10, d9        ;  d10 := d9   // now d8, d9 and d10 contains 1.0 !!!
vdivd   d8, d8, d10      ;  d8 := d8 / d10 = 1.0
vadd    d8, d8, d9       ;  d8 := d8 + d9 = 2.0
vmov.f64  d11, d8
```

Well the code produced by JIT looks completely wrong. Instead of three only one constant is read 1.0, and as a result we receive the computation of `X = 1.0 + 1.0 / 1.0` which not surprisingly evaluates to 2.0

And here is the JIT output for Dalvik run with `kLoadStoreElimination` optimization disabled (which fixes the bug):

```
D/dalvikvm: Dumping LIR insns
D/dalvikvm: installed code is at 0x45d64000
D/dalvikvm: total size is 124 bytes
D/dalvikvm: 0x45d64000 (0000): data    0x5260(21088)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45d64002 (0002): data    0x4572(17778)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45d64004 (0004): data    0x0044(68)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45d64006 (0006): ldr     r0, [r15pc, -#8]
D/dalvikvm: 0x45d6400a (000a): ldr     r1, [r0, #0]
D/dalvikvm: 0x45d6400c (000c): adds    r1, r1, #1
D/dalvikvm: 0x45d6400e (000e): str     r1, [r0, #0]
D/dalvikvm: -------- entry offset: 0x0000
D/dalvikvm: L0x45717274:
D/dalvikvm: -------- dalvik offset: 0x0000 @ const-wide/high16 v0, (#16368), (#0)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45d64010 (0010): vldr    d8, [r15, #96]
D/dalvikvm: -------- dalvik offset: 0x0002 @ const-wide/high16 v2, (#16352), (#0)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45d64014 (0014): vldr    d10, [r15, #76]
D/dalvikvm: 0x45d64018 (0018): vldr    d9, [r15, #80]
D/dalvikvm: 0x45d6401c (001c): vstr    d9, [r5, #8]
D/dalvikvm: -------- dalvik offset: 0x0004 @ const-wide/high16 v4, (#16592), (#0)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45d64020 (0020): vstr    d10, [r5, #16]
D/dalvikvm: -------- dalvik offset: 0x0006 @ div-double/2addr v0, v4, (#0)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45d64024 (0024): vdivd   d8, d8, d10
D/dalvikvm: -------- dalvik offset: 0x0007 @ add-double/2addr v0, v2, (#0)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45d64028 (0028): vadd    d8, d8, d9
D/dalvikvm: 0x45d6402c (002c): vstr    d8, [r5, #0]
D/dalvikvm: -------- dalvik offset: 0x0008 @ return-wide v0, (#0), (#0)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45d64030 (0030): vmov.f64  d11, d8
D/dalvikvm: 0x45d64034 (0034): vstr    d11, [r6, #16]
D/dalvikvm: 0x45d64038 (0038): blx_1   0x45d63028
D/dalvikvm: 0x45d6403a (003a): blx_2   see above
D/dalvikvm: 0x45d6403c (003c): b       0x45d64040 (L0x45718050)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45d6403e (003e): undefined
D/dalvikvm: L0x45718050:
D/dalvikvm: -------- reconstruct dalvik PC : 0x457313f4 @ +0x0008
D/dalvikvm: 0x45d64040 (0040): ldr     r0, [r15pc, #28]
D/dalvikvm: Exception_Handling:
D/dalvikvm: 0x45d64044 (0044): ldr     r1, [r6, #108]
D/dalvikvm: 0x45d64046 (0046): blx     r1
D/dalvikvm: -------- end of chaining cells (0x0048)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45d64060 (0060): .word (0x457313f4)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45d64064 (0064): .word (0)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45d64068 (0068): .word (0x40d00000)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45d6406c (006c): .word (0)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45d64070 (0070): .word (0x3fe00000)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45d64074 (0074): .word (0)
D/dalvikvm: 0x45d64078 (0078): .word (0x3ff00000)
D/dalvikvm: End LCalc;calcX, 6 Dalvik instructions
```

All three constants loaded as expected and correct evaluation is performed.